# Perform a query with regular expressions in Orion-LD Context Broker

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

This is my request:

```
http://localhost:1026/ngsi-ld/v1/entities?q=measurementVariable~=*temperature
```

This is the answer:

```
{
    "type": "https://uri.etsi.org/ngsi-ld/errors/BadRequestData",
    "title": "ngsi-ld query language: after match operator must come a RegExp",
    "detail": "Variable"
}
```

I have tried several regular expressions and get the same error every time. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```bash
curl -L -X GET 'http://localhost:1026/ngsi-ld/v1/entities/?q=name~=.*'
```

Should work. `*` on its own is not a valid Regex.

Comment: I tried that and got the same error.

Comment: I have updated my question to reflect the request I really want to make.

Comment: @T.R. - Which release of Orion-LD are you using? The  mongo-db drivers are currently being upgraded. I was using the latest pre-release. `fiware/orion-ld:1.1.0-PRE-961 `

Comment: @T.R. `*temperature` ia still not a valid regex.  Either you are looking for all variables ending with "temperature" which is `.*temperature` or you are looking for  the specific string `\*temperature` (where `*` is properly escaped. An asterisk on its own is never a valid regex.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say `.*temperature`. In my `docker-compose.yml` file I have 6 services - `fiware/iotagent-ul`, `fiware/orion-ld`, `mongo`, `fiware/mintaka`, `timescale/timescaledb-ha`, `nodered` and `eclipse-mosquitto`; I deleted all these images and started over and now it works! Strange is that the version of Orion-LD I had before and the one I have now is exactly the same - `post-v1.0.1`. I don't know what happened, but it works now. @JasonFox

Answer (score 0):

Orion-LD had a bug in the REGEX processing. Fixed it just a few weeks ago. My guess is you actually got a newer version of the broker.